# Whats the best practice to use more than one title inside UL tags

Tags: html, css, html-lists, title

I'm building this menu with an `<ul>` tag, that will have a title and then the correspondent menus. I wanted to know how is the best practice with this kind of task and SEO too.

I though about:

```
<ul>
   <li><h2>Books</h2></li>
   <li>Portuguese</li>
   <li>Italian</li>
   <li><h2>Movies</h2></li>
   <li>Indonesia</li>
   <li>Thailand</li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
<h2>Books</h2>   
<ul>
   <li>Portuguese</li>
   <li>Italian</li>
</ul>

<h2>Movies</h2>   
<ul>
   <li>Indonesia</li>
   <li>Thailand</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a better approach? If not, which of these two is better, and why?

Comment: I think the second way is better, as the first way means the titles will show as list items. Also, make sure to properly close your end tags `</ul>`.

Comment: I tought that too at first, but then it occured that if I wanted this to be generated dynamically with PHP or ASP it could be diferentt in some way I'm not seeing.

Comment: Have a look a this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555014/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-place-h2-tags-between-li-tags

Comment: I would use `h2` tags under `ul`(Not in `li`). It's easier while selecting them also.

Comment: @Litestone, you mean above? <h2> tag on top of the list?

Comment: I think you should use `<nav>` instead of ul. Since `<nav>` its technically create for navigation menus. Ul used to be the standard IMHO

Comment: This is an opinion poll, or “primarily opinion-based”, hence off-topic.

Comment: I mean `<ul><h2></h2><li></li><li></li></ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way because the first one will be rendering the `h2` element inside of the unordered list. Another reason is that the second one is just cleaner and easier to manage what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Mix of both is better:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <h2>Books</h2>   
       <ul>
           <li>Portuguese</li>
           <li>Italian</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

It's a lot easier to do menu more interactive this way. Take a look [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3).